# Add quantity in eshop in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I built an eshop and struggle find the syntax in order to multiply quantity of a product in the "Cart". I have managed to "add to cart" the products however does not update the quantity
of the product added. It adds the product everytime I click "addToCart". I am using redux so I know that I should write additional code in the reducer file.
My reducer file code is the following:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from './constants'
import { REMOVE_FROM_CART } from './constants'


const initialState = {
    cart: [],
  }
const ShoppinReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const newCart = [...state.cart]
      
      newCart.push(action.payload)
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: newCart
      }

    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      const cart = [...state.cart]
      const updatedCart = cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: updatedCart
      }
    
    default:
    return state
  }
}
  export default ShoppinReducer
```

and my "Cart" component is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Card, CardBody, CardHeader, CardTitle, Row, Col } from "reactstrap"
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js"
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { removeCart} from "../redux/actions";


class Cart extends Component {
   removeFromCart = (product) => {
    const cartProducts = this.props.cart 
    const updatedCartProducts = cartProducts.filter(item => item.id !== product.id);
  
  }

  render () {
    const cartProducts = this.props.cart
    return (
      <>
        <PanelHeader size="sm" />
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col xs={12}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h4">Products List</CardTitle>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>#</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Code Item</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                      <th scope="col"><strong>Price Total</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {cartProducts.length > 0 && cartProducts.map((cartProduct, index) => (             
                      <tr key={cartProduct.id}>
                    <th scope="row">{index +1}</th>
                    <td>{cartProduct.title}</td>
                    <td>{cartProduct.code}</td>
                    <td>{cartProduct.quantity}</td>
                    <td>{cartProduct.price}</td>
                    <td><button onClick ={() => this.props.removeCart(cartProduct)} className="btn btn-danger cart-button px-4">Remove</button></td>
                      </tr>))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
      cart: state.cart
       }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { 
      return {
        removeCart: (product) => {dispatch(removeCart(product))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

Bare in mind that "addToCart" button lives in other component however, I posted "Cart" component in order to display how the structure of the "Cart" is!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does your `cart` structure look like?

Comment: @ Prajwal Kulkarni The cart consists of a table with Number, Name, Code, Quantity and Total Price and last but not least of a remove button when an item added on it! I posted the "Cart" component code in order to addittional help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before pushing any item to your cart, you need to check whether the items already exist in the cart or not, if it exists you should update the quantity instead. You can rewrite the `ADD_TO_CART` case in your reducer to something like this:

```
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
  }
const ShoppinReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      let newCart = [...state.cart]
      let itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(obj=>obj.id===action.payload.id)  
      let currItem = state.cart[itemIndex]

      if(currItem){
            currItem.quantity = parseInt(currItem.quantity) + 1
            state.cart[itemIndex] = currItem
            newCart = [...state.cart]
        }
        else{
            
            newCart = newCart.concat(action.payload)
        }
        
        return {
          cart: newCart
        }

    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      const cart = [...state.cart]
      const updatedCart = cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: updatedCart
      }
    
    default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however still does not update quantity in my "Cart" component! Still pushes an item to array!

Comment: In your `addToCart` function, are you dispatching the the action where the data is nested in `payload`? i.e Does your dispatch look  something like `dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART. payload:{id:123,name:'ProductName',quantity:1}` ? Also, is your remove item working properly ?

Comment: Kulkarini Answer to your first question is the following: export const addCart = (product) => {
 return {
  type: ADD_TO_CART,
  payload: product
  }
}
And answer to 2nd question yes remove item is working properly!
I do not find a workaround to solve it!

Comment: I've slightly edited the logic, kindly try and see if it works.

Comment: Still the same Prawjwal! Seems either this way not working!

Comment: If a new item is being pushed to the array instead of updating it, I feel there's some error in the object you are sending to the reducer. In the reducer function, we're checking if an object(item) exists which has the same id as the received object.  Could you try console logging and checking if item(s) are sent with the expected/correct ids ?

Comment: Yes, the items are sent correctly while console.logging. With the expected/correct ids!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238596/discussion-between-prajwal-kulkarni-and-shpongle).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. I would assume your cart state is something looking like this

```js
cart: [
  {itemId: '1', quantity: 1, price: 100, ...},
  {itemId: '2', quantity: 1, price: 200, ...}
]
```

The problem is your existing addToCart action will only push an item to the end of array, without checking if this was an item already exists in the cart. Eventually the cart end up like

```js
cart: [
  {itemId: '1', quantity: 1, price: 100, ...},
  {itemId: '2', quantity: 1, price: 200, ...},
  {itemId: '1', quantity: 1, price: 100, ...}
]
```

So you need to check if you're adding a new item or an existing item, if it is an existing item, you need to update the existing item quantity rather than pushing it to the array.

Comment: @ spiritwalker Yes that's my case! I manage to push item to array (add it) without really update the already added item's quantity!

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the item is already in the list when the `ADD_TO_CART` action is executed. It could be something like

```
const alreadyInList = state.cart.find(item => item.id === action.payload.id);
let newCart;
if (alreadyInList) { // increments quantity if item already in list
  newCart = state.cart.map(item => {
    if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
      return {..item, quantity: item.quantity + 1};
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });
} else { // adds item to the end if it's not already in the list
  newCart = [...state.cart, payload.action];
}
return {..state, cart: newCart};
```

However, a JavaScript Array is not an adequate data structure for this kind of operation. It would be better if you used an object whose keys are de product IDs, and the values are the products themselves. Then you'd be able to check if an item is already present and update it more efficiently.

On a side note:

You check the length of cartProducts before mapping through the list

```
    {cartProducts.length > 0 && cartProducts.map((cartProduct, index) => (...
```

You don't need to do that, just `cartProducts.map((cartProduct, index) => (...` will suffice.

Also, you could take a look at react hooks and maybe redux toolkit. Both of these help to reduce boilerplate.

Comment: I followed your intsructions however it still adds products to cart, not updating quantity. The second suggestion from you works fine with mapping!

Answer (score 0):

As @spiritWalker says you have to implement that logic in the reducer. I give you an example:

```js
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const newCart = [...state.cart]
      
      const index = newCart.findIndex((item) => item.id == action.payload.id)
      // If index is -1, no similar items were found so we 
      // add the item to the cart.
      // Otherwise, the index of the item is returned and we use
      // it to update the quantity property of the existing item.
      if (index == -1) {
        newCart.push(action.payload)
      } else {
        newCart[index].quantity++
      }
      
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: newCart
      }
```

Also, I recommend you to give a try to the [Redux Toolkit Package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), which abstracts a lot of logic and boilerplate from Redux and can definitely make your code leaner and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the following code is working fine. I post it just in case someone else needs it for future reference!

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from './constants'
import { REMOVE_FROM_CART } from './constants'
// import { ADD_QUANTITY} from './constants'
// import { SUB_QUANTITY}  from './constants'
// import { EMPTY_CART}  from './constants'


const initialState = {
    cart: [],
  }
const ShoppinReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      
      let newCart = [...state.cart]

      let itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(obj=>obj.id===action.payload.id)
      
         
      let currItem = state.cart[itemIndex]

      if(currItem){
      currItem.quantity = parseInt(currItem.quantity) + 1
      state.cart[itemIndex] = currItem
      newCart = [...state.cart]
      }
      else {

      newCart = newCart.concat(action.payload)
      }

      return {
      cart: newCart
      }

    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      const cart = [...state.cart]
      const updatedCart = cart.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: updatedCart
      }
    
    default:
    return state
  }
}
  export default ShoppinReducer
```